# Set a breakpoint before WriteFile operation in OllyDbg

Tags: windows, debuggers, ollydbg

In the process monitor, I see a `WriteFile` operation. How can I set a breakpoint and view everything about this operation in OllyDbg?

If this is not possible with OllyDbg, what other tools can I use?

Answer (score 4):

From http://www.ollydbg.de/faq.htm -

> **How can I set breakpoint on a call to API function, like MessageBoxA?**
>
> This is very simple now. Either open command line (Alt+F1) and type "BPX MessageBoxA", or search for all itermodular calls in
> Disassembler, click on any call to MessageBoxA and set breakpoint on
> every call to this function.
>
> If you are a happy owner of Windows NT,
> 2000 or XP, you can set breakpoint directly on the API function in
> system DLL. Name window contains special menu item "breakpoint on
> import". In many cases, logging breakpoint that writes call arguments
> to the log file is a good alternative to ordinary break.

Comment: @JansonGreffner yes thanks for ur answer i saw this but i cant found the writefile on ollydbg

Comment: @jason this has landed me in a very interesting switch statement. Thanks